# In a PoW(Proof-of-Work) blockchain of length N, how difficult is to modify the (N-2)th block?

Tags: blockchain

So I was going through a few resources([link](https://lhartikk.github.io/)) on how to implement a `PoW Blockchain`, and reaod this:

> If the data in block 44 is changed from “DESERT” to “STREET”, all
>   hashes of the consecutive blocks must be changed. This is because the
>   hash of the block depends on the value of the previousHash (among
>   other things).
>
> This is an especially important property when proof-of-work is
>   introduced. The deeper the block is in the blockchain, the harder it
>   is to modify it, since it would require modifications to every
>   consecutive block.

So, consider a private blockchain of length, say **7**, how difficult would it be for someone to modify the **5th block**?

Comment: Modification itself is not difficult. The difficult part is convincing the network to accept your version of the blockchain as the true one.

Comment: Could you share the resources? I'd like to glance through. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev edited the post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "difficult". Technically, it's not difficult at all, all you need to do is recompute all of the elements after the one that was modified. This is straightforward and cheap (if you have ever worked with git, that's exactly what happens if you do a rebase with 5 commits).

Of course, that will give you five new hashes, so everybody immediatelly notices that someone has manipulated the blockchain. What "bad guys" would try to do is manipulate the blockchain *but keeping the hashes constant*. With a good hash algorithm, *that* is very difficult and computationally expensive to do in a way that gives you an identical hash *and* the change is somehow meaningful (i.e. to their advantage).

Update: 
If you can do it for one hash, you can manipulate the entire chain, because the descendants depend only on that hash. So it's the same effort whichever element you want to tamper with. (but this may be implementation-dependent).

Comment: Agree, this is no difficult at all, if (and this is a very big if) there are no other workers. I think, what Ayush is asking about, is the 51% attack, not the hash collision attack (this one does not seem viable at all)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Ok, that's when it's about cryptographic currencies for instance. Blockchains of course have different uses, where the majority rule isn't used (git for instance also uses kind of a blockchain)

Comment: the term PoW gives it away, what kind of blockchain this is :)